# How to hide certain values in SQL Reporting Services

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I am creating a report in SSRS 2005 and where there should be a NULL value in the table it is returning a value ("Alle" [the tables are mostly in German]). This isn't really a problem as I think I can hide the value as explained here:

[How to hide certain on SQL Reporting Services 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227565/how-to-hide-certain-on-sql-reporting-services-2005?answertab=active#tab-top)

However, when I add `=Replace(Fields!LengthofFunding.Value,"Alle","")` to the Expression box in the field I want to hide the value for it is returning a FALSE value rather than a blank.

Can anyone let me know how I can make this field return a blank value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of replace you can use the **Iif** as following:

```
=Iif(Fields!LengthofFunding.Value = "Alle", " " , Fields!LengthofFunding.Value )
```

This means if its equal to "Alle" replace with blank, else keep the original value.